# How to use Hibernate filter with array

Tags: hibernate

I would like to limit my queries to allowed channel IDs (security reasons). This approach doesn't work:

```
@FilterDef(name = "channelFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "channelIds", type = "long[]"))
@Filter(name = "channelFilter", condition = "id IN (:channelIds)")
```

I wonder if it would be even possible to set allowed list of ids from `List<Long> channelIds`.